# Why would GNU Make run sequential even though I've added --jobs and --max-load isn't even close?

Tags: bash, makefile, parallel-processing

This is on GNU Make 3.82, RHEL 7. Make appears to be running sequentially even though I passed in `--jobs`.

I'm doing about 700K trivial jobs - concatenating large gzip files onto other gzip files. If there is only one file to concatenate, then I create a symbolic link instead. Here is the command:

```bash
# Pattern to rebuild gzip file - concatenate if needed, otherwise just link
$(THISDIR)/%.tgz:
    mkdir -p $$(dirname $@) && \
    if [ $$(echo '$^' | wc -w) -gt 1 ]; then cat $^ > $@; else ln -s $^ $@; fi
```

I already separated by `&&` to avoid another shell invocation, made no difference.

About 600K of the 700K jobs are just creating symbolic links. For the remainder, the average number of files to concatenate is four.

Why is this so slow? I'm getting 5-8 TPS. More importantly, even though I specified (on a machine with 64 CPUS):

```
make --jobs --max-load=48
```

I see very few processes on `top`. So it appears that Make is not running parallel jobs at all. Is there a minimal job length for parallelism to work efficiently on GNU Make?

The load average from `top` right now is

```
top - 22:50:32 up 3 days, 13:13, 32 users,  load average: 7.96, 7.44, 5.73
```

A few further details that might be helpful:

1. Make itself is running at close to 100% CPU.
2. There is no dependency between any of the files other than, of course, target and dependencies on the same rule. In other words, there are no files that appear both in `$@` and `$^`.
3. Files are being created and read from NFS mounts
4. I've generated the 700K dependencies as rules that get read into the Makefile with an `include`. That process itself takes 25 minutes or so.

Comment: A single makefile with 700K targets is a LOT.  Since you say that make itself is using 100% CPU it seems likely that make is struggling with some of its internal structures that maybe weren't designed for that number of targets.  A typical large build might have 20K targets or so.  One thing to try is moving to a newer version of GNU make.  There have definitely been performance improvements since 3.82 was released over 10 years ago.  I can't necessarily point to a specific one however so I can't guarantee it will help.

Comment: Have you considered using something other than `make` for this?  Maybe a straight-up shell script?  Performance considerations notwithstanding, it sounds like your problem is not one that gets much leverage from `make`.

Comment: I have considered - I use GNU Parallel extensively in other workflows. But what I was looking for in this case was the dependency resolution. If 15 files change upstream, I want to rebuild the 5-15 that depend on them, not all the 700K. But I wasn't expecting the performance of Make to be this bad on what is essentially a bipartite multi-graph. It is probably optimised for some more general graph structures.

Comment: Is it possible that you try a `$(wildcard $(THISDIR)/*.tgz):` instead of the pattern rule?

Comment: Na, Vroom. The folder structure underneath `$(THISDIR)` is complex.

Comment: There is a recursive `wildcard` function in gmtt: https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/blob/b736ff23a6ccd54b56bf581bbbd5c0ef339ab710/gmtt.mk#L1379 Would this help?

Answer (score 2):

Possible to improve performance, especially when large number of files are being rebuilt by using (gnu) make functions to replace shell commands. This will reduce the umber of 'fork' and 'exec' required to complete the tasks:

```
%.tgz:
        mkdir -p $(<D) && \
        $(if $(findstring $(words $^),1),ln -s $^ $@, cat $^ > $@)
```

For the mkdir command, using the `$(<D)` will eliminate the call to `dirname`

For the `cat`/`ln` command, using `$(findstring ...)` and `words` will replace the `echo ... | wc` pipe, and the `$if(...)` will replace the shell if statement.

Overall, only 2 commands (mkdir, cat/ln), instead of 5 commands (mkdir, dirname, echo, wc, cat/ln) per target. Performance is about 2X

Answer (score 1):

Make was spending a large portion of the prep time trying to match each of the targets to all the built-in rules for things like C files. Adding

```
.SUFFIXES:
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules
```

made a huge difference. It still spends a few minutes after reading all the patterns in, but the benefits now outweigh that cost.